# Running a script with getopts works the first time, but doesn't work the second time I run it

Tags: bash, shell, command-line-arguments, getopts

This is my script.  I adapted it from [this tutorial](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial) so it can't be an error in the script itself. (The original script had the same problem.)

```
#!/bin/bash

while getopts "a:" opt; do
  case $opt in
    a)
      echo "-a was triggered, Parameter: $OPTARG"
      ;;
  esac
done
```

Here's my output:

```
bash-3.2$ source getopt.sh
bash-3.2$ source getopt.sh -a /dev/null
-a was triggered, Parameter: /dev/null
bash-3.2$ source getopt.sh -a /dev/null
bash-3.2$
```

I've combed the Internet and can't find any explanation for this behavior.

Comment: Why do you use `source` to run the script?

Comment: @choroba What difference does it make?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`source` runs the bash commands in the indicated file within the execution context of the current shell. That execution context includes the variable `OPTIND` which `getopts` uses to remember the "current" argument index. So when you repeatedly `source` the script, each invocation of `getopts` starts at the argument index after the last argument processed by the previous invocation.

Either reset `OPTIND` to 1 at the beginning of the script or invoke the script with `bash getopt.sh`. (Normally `getopts` is invoked as part of a script which is run through a she-bang execution, so it has its own execution context and you don't have to worry about its variables.)

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.  Thank you.